# Circular reference issue with struct and enum class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a header file (A):

```
namespace CChristianLifeMinistryDefines
{
    using S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM = struct tagDiscussionHistItem
    {
        CString strName;
        Schools eSchool;
        COleDateTime datMeeting;
    };
    using DiscussionItemHistList = list<S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM>;
}
```

The above header file is included in another header file (B):

```
#include "ChristianLifeMinistryDefines.h"
using namespace CChristianLifeMinistryDefines;

enum class Schools
{
    kMain,
    kClass1,
    kClass2,

    kCount
};
```

The problem I have (and I understand why) is that `Schools` is referred to in the `S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM` structure which is defined before the `Schools` enum.

> Error C3646: 'eSchool': unknown override specifier

The enum was already defined in my project and can't be moved else things might break down when compiling.

What I have done is move the class definition from file B to file A. But was there another solution to this? I couldn't simply include header B in header A because I get a circular reference and I can't get my head around what I found on the internet.

Comment: how about forward declaration ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: @Landstalker When I try using `enum class Schools;` it then complains about `Schools` being ambiguous.

Comment: Did you add the forward declaration, `enum class Schools;`, within `CChristianLifeMinistryDefines` namespace, by any chance? Header `B` defines it in the global namespace, so the forward declaration should be in the global namespace, too. Otherwise, you end up with declarations for two distinct enum types both named `Schools`.

Comment: Alternatively, move the whole definition of `Schools` to header A, before the definition of `S_DISCUSSION_HIST_ITEM`. Again, make sure to define it outside of `CChristianLifeMinistryDefines` namespace

Comment: @IgorTandetnik All good now. I accidentally declared it in the namespace by mistake.